# Inherit pthread local data

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have trying to see if there is in pthread a way to inherit thread local data,like `InheritableThreadLocal` in Java.

What I mean by that is that if Thread `A`, with a key `my_key = 2` spawns a Thread B, then Thread `B` is spawned with the same key `my_key = 2`.

```
void callback(...) {...}

main()


library_set_callback_on_data_retrieved(callback)

--- Start thread A ---> call_black_box_library(library_specific_params...) ---> calls callback in another_thread

--- Start thread B ---> call_black_box_library(library_specific_params...) --> calls callback in another_thread
```

In my callback, I would need a specific identifier to know from which thread the callback originates, but they are ran in another thread by the library and I do not know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pthread_create` allows to pass a `void*`  pointer to the starting thread – if you don't have other data to pass to you might cast the value to set to `void*` and in the new thread cast back, finally assign that value to `m_key` – assuming the latter is declared `thread_local`.

Comment: And perhaps making the data `thread_local` isn't really that useful if you're going to share it anyway?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I assume only an initial state is shared while later on data might diverge in between the two threads…

Comment: Hi @TedLyngmo, the idea is to only give access to some threads, while other thread will share a different set of data

Comment: Perhaps you want [`pthread_key_create`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_key_create.html) / `pthread_setspecific` / `pthread_getspecific`?

Comment: This may be a little bit of [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You clarify in comments that you are working with callbacks and a third party library. Can you illustrate that problem specifically, please?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Appears to me as the predecessor of `thread_local`, but we'd still need to access the specifics of the 'parent' thread, which pthreads has no notion of, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua The standard [`tss_create`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/tss_create) lives alongside with `thread_local`. I haven't used it but seems to me to be more of a dynamic allocation version of `thread_local` for _Key_ / _Value_ s.

Comment: @Paul thanks that is getting closer — can we see the parameters to the callback?  If there's a way to pass user-supplied data, for example, that will be important to some answers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo So we could have a thread_local pointer initialised to NULL to achieve the same again ;) Maybe the advantage of is rather the ability to create arbitrary number of keys dynamically, though not fully clear about how to handle all of these then, probably in a (dynamic) array?

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't fully understand why it exists either. It's just that the C standardization committee usually don't bring things in unless there's a real proven improvement to the language.

Comment: @TedLyngmo A thread-local dynamically allocated array is not the same as a global dynamically allocated array of `thread_local`s. For the latter I'd need `tss_create` (at least I failed to create it via `thread_local`). Though wondering what the use case could be for, maybe within some parallelising library like OpenMP?

Comment: In addition to providing the callback signature, two more questions. First, can you please explain when/how the callback runs?  Is it effectively synchronous — i.e., when `call_black_box_lib` returns, the callback is guaranteed to have run at most one time?  Can it run multiple times?  Is it truly asynch, invoked for example when some I/O arrives?  Second, are you sure that each callback runs in a newly spawned thread?  Some libraries would use a secret thread pool.  (SIGEV_THREAD is permitted to be implemented with a "thread pool" of one thread, for example.)

Comment: @Aconcagua _"A thread-local dynamically allocated array is not the same as a global dynamically allocated array of `thread_local`s."_ - Exacly. It's more like a hidden storage of `thread_local`s. Each thread may get the same _key_ value as the other threads, but the lookup still returns the thread specific value.

Comment: @pilcrow yes, it runs in a separate thread. There is a sync or async option, for some reason both of them spawn a new thread anyway, which seem kind of odd to me. one call to `call_black_box_lib` will always trigger the callback one and only one time (except if an error happens, but there is another callback specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have trying to see if there is in pthread a way to inherit thread local data,like InheritableThreadLocal in Java.

**TL;DR: No, pthreads does not offer anything analogous to `InheritableThreadLocal`.**  Nor does it in general attribute significance to which thread starts which, unlike Java.

The closest pthreads feature is thread-specific data, the primary interfaces to which are [pthread_key_create()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_key_create), [pthread_setspecific() and pthread_getspecific()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_getspecific), and [pthread_key_delete()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_key_delete).  The documentation for `pthread_key_create()` explains that

> Upon key creation, the value NULL shall be associated with the new key in all active threads. Upon thread creation, the value NULL shall be associated with all defined keys in the new thread.

No exceptions are documented, so no, this feature does not provide for one thread to inherit thread-specific data from another.

Going a bit further afield, since C11, the C language has had built-in support for threads, including a set of functions closely analogous to pthreads.  Its analogs to the pthreads functions discussed above are `tss_create()`, `tss_set()`, `tss_get()`, and `tss_delete()`, and they have the same semantics with respect to (non-)inheritance of thread-specific storage.

C11 also defines a new "thread" storage duration, specified via the new `_Thread_local` storage class specifier.  For most purposes, this is a simpler entry into thread-local data.  But this feature does not provide for inheriting data from one thread to another either.  Each thread-local object is initialized when its thread is created, either to the value specified by its initializer, or if it has no initializer then to a default value that, approximately speaking, is all-zero.

> In my callback, I would need a specific identifier to know from which
> thread the callback originates, but they are ran in another thread by
> the library and I do not know how to do that.

Your callback could use any of those forms of thread-local data to recognize that multiple calls to that or other callbacks are performed by the same thread, and to share data among those calls, but only on a single-thread basis.  These mechanisms do not provide for relating the callback calls of one thread to those of any other.

Answer (score 0):

Pthreads allow to forward data to the new threads main routine via a `void*` pointer, see [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

You can use this mechanism to pass the value to the new thread. If there's further data to be sent create a struct containing all data, if there's only the value you might just cast it to `void*`. Once the new thread has started it would just write the value to the variable – assuming it is declared `thread_local`. This might look as follows:

```
thread_local int m_key; // or whatever other type

// fails if your whatever other type doesn't fit into a void*:
char compileTimeCheck[1 - 2*(sizeof(int) > sizeof(void*))];

void* threadRoutine(void* p)
{
    m_key = (int)(intptr_t)p;

    // ...

    return NULL; // or whatever meaningful
}

int main(void)
{
    m_key = 2;

    // ...

    pthread_t thread;
    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &threadRoutine, (void*)(intptr_t)(m_key)) != 0)
    {
        // TODO: error handling
    }
    else
    {
        // thread OK

        // ...

        pthread_join(thread, NULL); // or pointer to a void* variable if thread_routine
                                    // has something meaningful to return
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Es6WMesqj).

If there are more values to be provided than fit into a `void*` pointer then I'd recommend a struct and possibly passing copies of to the new thread:

```
struct Keys
{
    // whatever keys
};

thread_local struct Keys m_allKeys = {/*...*/};

void* threadRoutine(void* p)
{
    memcpy(&m_allKeys, p, sizeof(m_allKeys));
    free(p);

    // ...

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    // ...

    void* keys = malloc(sizeof(m_allKeys));
    if(!keys)
    {
        // TODO: error handling
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(keys, &m_allKeys, sizeof(m_allKeys));

        pthread_t thread;
        if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &threadRoutine, keys) != 0)
        {
            free(keys); // avoid memory leak!
            // TODO: error handling
        }
        else
        {
            // thread OK

            // ...

            pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z9nPaqd85).

Side note: If you want to avoid a copy and pass `&m_allKeys` directly you need to avoid race conditions in between the new thread still copying the data and the old thread starting to modify it again after thread creation by some appropriate means.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, sadly I only have a callback and I do not instantiate the thread myself, it is done by a third party library. I myself spawn multiple threads, and each of those threads may spawn another thread in which my callback is called. This is this callback that should use the local data, hence the reason I asked if there was a mechanism to share local data without passing it explicitely.

Comment: @Paul Is there a `void*` pointer in the callback you can provide a value for? You then could have a struct containing a mutex, parent thread locks that one on modifying the struct, the callbacks would lock it on copying it.

Comment: On a second thought, having a pair of these structs might avoid quite some locking, you'd use one of for normal processing, then lock mutex and copy to second one before calling the thread-creation function.

Comment: Aconcagua no, I am sadly not the one that calls the callback, and the callback is the same for every thread

Comment: @Paul That wasn't what I meant – it doesn't matter *who* calls the callback as long as there's an option to pass custom user data to via (typically) a `void*` pointer.

Comment: Well I do not think so. However I am intrigued, how would that work ?

Comment: @Paul Actually not any differently. That function you call would accept the callback and an additional `void*` pointer, similar to [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YP5c5djzK).